# Do or don't: two url's to same page

Tags: routes, seo

I have a blog where I can view a blog article by entering the following url:
[http://www.kattenbelletjes.be/blog/2016/05/12/spaghetti](http://www.kattenbelletjes.be/cooking/2016/05/12/spaghetti)

There are some tags on the blog so I can group specific blog articles. An example url:
http://www.kattenbelletjes.be/blog/tag/cooking

When I'm viewing a blog article (= view action), I want to remember if there was a tag clicked before the blog article was opened. I could make this url work:
http://www.kattenbelletjes.be/blog/tag/cooking/2016/05/12/spaghetti

But with SEO on my mind: is it OK to do this? Can I create 2 different links (link 1 & link 3) to the same page? I have a bad feeling that Google doesn't like this...

If my concern is right: what should I do instead? Using sessions or...?

Thx
 :)

Comment: Read up on rel=canonical

Comment: Oh, never heard of it. Great stuff, thanks 4 the tip!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned (very briefly) in the comments.

Yes this will look bad for SEO as it will look like duplicate content.

You can add a rel=canonical link to the HEAD of one of the pages to tell search engines that this is a copy and where the preferred version is located:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/original/article" />
```

More info here: https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/m

However there are other ways to achieve what you want to. You could add an otherwise meaningless URL parameter for example which would allow you to have just one page:

http://www.kattenbelletjes.be/cooking/2016/05/12/spaghetti?tag=cooking